# Nefesh HaChaim building and destroying worlds

Tags: mitzvah, mysticism-kabbalah, nefesh-hachaim

the Nefesh HaChaim part 1 states that acts of mitzva build mystical worlds whereas acts of sin destroy mystical worlds. (Shaar 1 chapter 3<sup>1</sup>). What sources go into more details as to these worlds and what happens.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>כן בדמיון זה כביכול ברא הוא יתברך את האדם והשליטו על רבי רבוון כחות ועולמות אין מספר. ומסרם בידו שיהא הוא המדבר והמנהיג אותם עפ''י כל פרטי תנועות מעשיו ודבוריו ומחשבותיו וכל סדרי הנהגותיו הן לטוב או להיפך ח''ו כי במעשיו ודבוריו ומחשבותיו הטובים **הוא מקיים ונותן כח בכמה כחות ועולמות עליונים הקדושים ומוסיף בהם קדושה ואור** כמ''ש (ישעי' נ''א) ואשים דברי בפיך גו' לנטוע שמים וליסוד ארץ. וכמאמרם ז''ל אל תקרא בניך אלא בוניך כי המה המסדרים עולמות העליוני' כבונה המסדר בנינו ונותנים בהם רב כח ובהיפוך ח''ו ע''י מעשיו או דבוריו ומחשבותיו אשר לא טובים. **הוא מהרס ר''ל כמה כחות ועולמות עליונים הקדושים לאין ערך ושיעור**. כמ''ש (שם מ''ט) מהרסיך ומחריביך וגו'. או מחשיך או מקטין אורם וקדושתם ח''ו. ומוסיף כח לעומת זה במדורות הטומאה ר''ל:  ‏</sub>

Comment: Did you try checking any commentaries to Nefesh HaChaim?

Comment: @DoubleAA no... you know of some online?

Comment: The NH itself wrote sources